# Music player device from Star Trek Beyond

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

Around the middle of the movie Star Trek Beyond there's some sort of **music player device** playing the song "Fight the Power" by Public Enemy.

Does that device exist for real, or is possibly built out of an existing device? If so, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 3):

The device in question was found aboard a Starfleet spacecraft.  This would be akin to expecting to find a Victrola aboard a USS Naval ship.  The device hasn't been created yet.

[image]

It's clearly meant to be a rack-mounted device (note the handles on each side), yet the object is angled on the sides.  I've never seen any rack that would be able to hold something like this.

The scene in question starts at the 58:00 mark, in case you're wanting to take a look yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I still think someone might recognize the display and the EQ lights from a real device, maybe they didn't build the whole thing from scratch but instead just modded something.

Comment: Movie electronics props are often custom made and not fully functional.

Comment: I doubt it's anything more than plastic, leds and maybe a digital picture frame. Not a physically working radio.

Comment: First of all, the LEDs on the right and left pretty much stayed lit through the entire scene, making their functionality questionable.  Secondly, the amount of info they might be trying to display in the center section makes it incomprehensible, aside from the wave graphic (although even that was suspect as it doesn't show each channel separately).  Lastly, the buttons are just too small to be form-functional.  The only thing that gives bortran's comment credence is that I can't see a prop department creating 7,000 new pieces of technology.